# Javascript Variable Scope Issue Nested Functions

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

Alright, so I'm semi-new to Javascript and I'm overhauling an extension for a friend.

My issue is that my chrome.browserAction.getTitle gets the right data but the function does not pass the result to the main function, showing up as "undefined" in the function called "setBadge".

```
function setBadge(status,s) {
    chrome.browserAction.getTitle({}, function(result){
        console.log(result)
        setBadge(res)
    });

    console.log(s);
    chrome.browserAction.setTitle({title:("is " + status)});

    if (status == "Online" && result == "is Offline") {
        showOn();
        audioNotification();
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text:("On" + "            ")});
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({color:([0,255,0,255])});
    }

    if (status == "Offline" && result == "is Online") {
        showOff();
        audioNotification();
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text:("Off" + "            ")});
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({color:([255,0,0,100])});
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have `setBadge()` calling `setBadge()` with only one argument (which is `undefined`) and calling it over and over and over again.  Neither of those situations seems correct.

Comment: You don't show how the posted code is called or where *res* is initialised or declared.

Answer (score 0):

So what I see first of all are two things.

1. SetBadge is never called in this snippet outside itself leading to infinite recursion and

2 inside you pass `res` to setBadge which is in fact undefined.

Comment: Attempting to pass *res* should throw a reference error since it's not defined or initialised in the posted code (though perhaps it is elsewhere).